# Grunt filerev, usemin and file caching

Tags: angularjs, caching, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt `filerev` task to add cachebusters to files when their content changes. `usemin` task to replace the relevant file path with their revved versions where they are referred. Everything is setup well and they are working as expected / written in their documentation.

I'll try to explain the issue now:

This is an Angular JS project where the simplified structure is somewhat like this:

```
a.html -> b.js -> c.html (partial)
```

Here a.html refers to b.js and b.js loads c.html as partial. The server is set to cache all these assets so cachebuster strings become important.

When I run `grunt build` to execute `filerev` and then `usemin`, it renames `c.html` to `c.[md5_hash_of_c].html`, `b.js` to `b.[md5_hash_of_b].js` and `a.html` to `a.[md5_hash_of_a].html`. After this it updates the reference line in `b.js` for `c.html` to `c.[md5_hash_of_c].html`. Similarly it updates `a.html` as well. This means that when the hashes were calculated, these files still had the unrevved version of other files referenced. As a result, when content of `c.html` changes, it updates its reference in `b.js` but doesn't update the name of `b.js` to reflect this change.

This defeats the very purpose of getting cache-busters in the file names. Because now browser has `b.[md5_hash_of_b].js` and `a.[md5_hahs_of_a].html` cached, the call for updated `c.[md5_hash_of_c].html` fails.

I was thinking that in the angular world and elsewhere as well, it should be a very standard practice, but couldn't see it discussed in detail anywhere. I'm looking for a workflow that can solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this issue discussed at [three](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/280) [different](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev/issues/85) [places](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/288). The third link is closest to the solution.

I finally ended up using `vermin` as a replacement task for `filerev` and `usemin` which internally executes both the tasks repeatedly until the filenames stop changing. It is shared as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/markrian/aa185c5ec66232a38a68

From gist comments:

```
/**
 * Vermin completely manages the running of the filerev and usemin tasks, so
 * that assets that reference other assets are correctly hashed after their
 * referenced assets are spliced in by usemin.
 *
 * Vermin also makes various assumptions about how filerev and usemin are set
 * up. For instance, it assumes that usemin runs immediately after filerev,
 * that filerev renames files in-place, and that usemin relies on
 * `grunt.filerev.summary`, as prepared by filerev (which vermin manipulates).
 * There may be other implicit assumptions that haven't been identified yet.
 *
 * Because grunt tasks can only be inserted into the task stack, to be run
 * sequentially, vermin recursively adds filerev, usemin and itself to the
 * stack to do its work. It maintains its state on the grunt object, and reads
 * that on each run to determine where in the process it is.
 */
```

Comment: hi! i hope you read this message after 5 years... i want to include vermin in my grunt task list, how can i do? there is no guide and i don't know hot to do. how i can reference vermin.js to gruntfile?